# Join attributes in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join few attributes in select statement using MySQL

```
SELECT 
        (Cast(n_socio As varchar), ' - ', nombre, ' ', apellidos) As DisplayItem,
        N_socio 
FROM     
        usuarios 
ORDER BY 
        n_socio
```

Comment: You've come to the right place. "It doesn't work" is SO's favourite phrase. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT 
        CONCAT(Cast(n_socio As varchar), ' - ', nombre, ' ', apellidos) As DisplayItem,
        N_socio 
FROM     
        usuarios 
ORDER BY 
        n_socio
```

Answer (score 1):

USE MySQL [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function like

```
SELECT CONCAT((Cast(n_socio AS varchar),' - ',nombre ,' ',apellidos)) AS DisplayItem,
       N_socio
FROM usuarios
ORDER BY n_socio
```